# Create Uneditable form control with a value from the ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working in the "Create.cshtml" view. I am trying to create an uneditable form-control with the value set using a value stored in the `ViewBag`. Something like:

```
@Html.Textbox(
    *model attribute*,
    *default value ie. (ViewBag.ID)*,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" @readonly="readonly" }
)
```

I havn't been able to figure out the correct syntax or even what kind of control I should be using. This is what a working version of the control looks like but does not have a preset value and is editable.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class ="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeagueID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeagueID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = true,value= ViewBag.LeagueId } })
```

Comment: How can I add a default value ViewBag.LeagueId to that?

Comment: @c3f just updated my answer, you can set the value property